# How do I convert a data frame into a binary/logical matrix in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, binary-matrix

So I have a data frame that contains a bunch of transactions with items, kinda like this:

```
| 1 | 2 | 4  | 5  | 6  |
| 3 | 5 | 8  | 9  |    |
| 1 | 5 | 7  | 10 | 12 |
| 7 | 8 | 10 | 15 | 17 |
```

I have a list of all the existing items, and now I'd like to convert this to a logical matrix with 0 and 1 values. So if an item exists in a given row, that entry in the matrix should be 1.

Is there an easy way to do this?

**Edit :**
For the logical matrix, we need to generate a column for each item, and a row for each transaction.

Comment: How do you define existence?

Comment: By existence I mean that it is present in that specific row. The rows have a varying number of items in them, but the item number does not correspond to the column index.

Comment: Try `tidyr:gather` to have tidy data, and then `table()`

Answer (score 3):

You may use `as.logical`.

```
# for a matrix
apply({m[is.na(m)] <- 0;m}, 2, as.logical)^1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    1    0
# [2,]    0    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    0    1

# works too on data frames
apply({d[is.na(d)] <- 0;d}, 2, as.logical)^1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    1    0
# [2,]    0    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    0    1
```

Or, using less bytes with credits to *@RHertel*:

```
d[] <- +!is.na(d)
```

*Data:*

```
m <- structure(c(1L, NA, 12L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 6L, NA, NA, 11L, 7L), .Dim = 3:4)
d <- as.data.frame(m)
```

Comment: Code-golf version: `d[] <- +!is.na(d)`. In any case the `apply` loops seem unnecessary here.

Comment: @RHertel Nice, I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame is called `df`, you can do:

```
df_matrix <- as.matrix(df)
df_matrix[!is.na(df_matrix)] <- 1
df_matrix[is.na(df_matrix)] <- 0
```

Comment: Thanks! The Problem is that my data frame does not have a column for every existing item. Every row only contains the items that are actually in that transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to make it:

Given `M <- as.matrix(df)` as the first step to convert data frame to matrix, then use

```
M[] <- ifelse(!is.na(M>0),1,0)
```

or

```
M[] <- +(!is.na(M>0))
```

you will get the binary matrix `M`